# Query events post type after current date and timezone

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, meta-query, events

So I am making changes to a clients website and currently they have an events post type with some custom fields that allow them to set an events end date/time and the events timezone.

The custom fields setup:

- Start Date and Time: text input / saves as php format `U`
- End Date and Time: text input / saves as php format `U`
- Timezone: select field / saves as string (e.g. `GMT` / `BST`)

And then on the front end their current wp_query is:

```
$events_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'     => 'events',
    'meta_key'      => 'start_date_and_time',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'    => [
        [
            'key'       => 'end_date_and_time',
            'value'     => date('U'),
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But this is not taking into account the timezone set in the backend compared to the timezone of the user.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`date()` PHP functions returns the value of `time()` PHP functions in the specified format. `time()` use server local time. If you want to get date/time based of WordPress configuration, you could use [`current_time()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time), a WordPress function, instead of native PHP functions.

```
// 'timestamp' = Unix Timestamp or 'U' PHP time format
$current_time = current_time( 'timestamp' );
```